# Getting the sum of all checked radio button values and returning the total

Tags: javascript, forms

I got a form built and I need it to get the  number value of all checked radio buttons, sum them and return the total on the same page.
My HTML and javascript code are below:

```
  <form>
    <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
  </form>
  <form>
     <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
    </form>
    <form>
       <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
    </form>
    <form>
       <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
    </form>

    <form>

       <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>

    </form>
    <form>
       <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
    </form>
    <form>

       <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
    </form>
    <form>
       <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
    </form>
    <form>
       <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
      <br>
    </form>
    <form>
      <p>Question here</p>
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
      <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    </form>
    <br>
      <input type ="button" name="resultButton" id = "totalSum" onclick = "handleClick();" value = "Get Result" >
      <br>
      <br>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function handleClick(input){
  var selected = document.getElementsByClassName(".check").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; ++i) { 
    if(selected.checked== true){
      alert("Your total is"+ i+ "...");
    }
    else{
      alert( "You didn't select an answer for all questions")
    }
  }  
};
```

Comment: You're not getting each selected items with that. It should be `selected[i].checked` and `var selected = document.getElementsByClassName(".check");`

Comment: @CodeLover Shouldn't `selected = document.getElementsByClassName(".check");` be `selected = document.getElementsByClassName("check");`. You only need the `.` to target a `class` with other query selectors or `jQuery` Also the `selected` variable is trying to return the `value` of those elements so your `for` loop isn't going to function as you intend.

Comment: Yeah. My mistake

Comment: Thank you all for the help. The weird thing is, the ideas you guys gave me work when I click the " Run code snippet" button on this page. But when I run from the IDE (Brackets) with the browser(Chrome) it always says : Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick.

Comment: Changed sentences to make more sense and removed extra explanations that made more sense.

Comment: Thank you @Syfer. It works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 mistakes in the code:

> 1. var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("check");
>      Removed the ".check" to "check"
> 2. The selected variable is array, so access each element `selected[i].checked`, index i is added.
> 3. You have a input parameter, even its not harm to run the code, but in HTML and JS code you are not using 'input' variable, so remove it.
> 4. Also according to question you need the sum, so you have to use a variable and sum if checkbox are checked.

Final code can be written as follows:

```
function handleClick(){
      var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("check");
      var totals = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; ++i) { 
      if(selected[i].checked == true){
         totals = totals + selected[i].value;

      }
       else{
           alert( "You didn't select an answer for all questions")
      }
 }
 alert("Your total is"+ totals + "...");  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code. You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to select all the `checked` radio buttons. Then use `forEach()` to calculate the total. Try the following way:

```js
function handleClick(input){
  var chk = document.querySelectorAll(".check:checked");
  var total = 0;
  if(!chk.length){
    alert( "You didn't select an answer for all questions")
  }
  else{
    chk.forEach(function(el){
       total += parseInt(el.getAttribute('value'));
    });
    alert("Your total is: "+ total);
  } 
};
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
</form>
<form>
   <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
  </form>
  <form>
     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
  </form>
  <form>
     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
  </form>

  <form>

     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>

  </form>
  <form>
     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
  </form>
  <form>

     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
  </form>
  <form>
     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
  </form>
  <form>
     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
    <br>
  </form>
  <form>
     <p>Question here</p>
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=1>never 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
    <input type="radio" class ="check" name="choose" value=4>always
  </form>
  <br>
    <input type ="button" name="resultButton" id = "totalSum" onclick = "handleClick();" value = "Get Result" >
    <br>
    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName("uncheck");
    var alen = all.length;
    while(alen--) {
      all[alen].onchange = function() {
        this.className = "check";
      }
    }
    function handleClick() {
      var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("check");
      var slen = selected.length;
      var answered = slen;
      var total = 0;
      while(slen--) {
        var se = selected[slen];
        if(se.checked) {
          total += parseInt(se.value);
        }
      }
      var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
      if(answered < questions.length) {
        alert("You didn't select an answer for all questions");
      }
      else {
        alert("Your total is " + total + " ...");
      }
    }
```

```html
enter code here
      <form>
        <p>Question here</p>
        <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
        <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
        <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
        <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
        <br>
      </form>
      <form>
         <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>
           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>
           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>
           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>
           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>

           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>
           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>
           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
          <br>
        </form>
        <form>
           <p>Question here</p>
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=1>never 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=2>sometimes 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=3>regularly 
          <input type="radio" class ="uncheck" name="choose" value=4>always
        </form>
        <br>
        <input type ="button" name="resultButton" id = "totalSum" onclick="handleClick()" value = "Get Result" >
```